# Why is matplotlib.patches.Circle not a circle?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a circle over a plot. Using the [Anatomy of a Figure](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/showcase/anatomy.html) for inspiration, I've created a short test code :

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib.patheffects import withStroke

fig = plt.figure()
x = np.arange(1,10,.1)
y3 = np.sin(x)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(1,1)  # 2x2 grid
ax=fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])
ax.plot(x,y3)
Xc = 6
Yc = 0.5
### This produces an ellipse
circle = Circle((Xc, Yc), 0.25, clip_on=False, zorder=10, linewidth=1,
                edgecolor='black', facecolor=(0, 0, 0, .0125),
                path_effects=[withStroke(linewidth=5, foreground='w')])
ax.add_artist(circle)
plt.show()
```

which generates the below plot [image: plot]

**Question** :

1. Why is the displayed 'circle' really an ellipse?

The help page for `Circle`, defines a resolution order, but it isn't obvious how this 'resolution' order is decided. Given that my `circle` is following the format of the above [Anatomy of a Figure](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/showcase/anatomy.html), I don't understand how this happens.

Comment: likely due to your xScale and yScale are different

Comment: `ax.set_aspect('equal')` will make that each axis has the same number of pixels for a given distance. Note that this will deform your subplot to be low and elongated. Alternatively, you could draw an ellipse using the inverse of the actual aspect ratio of the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your circle to look like a circle, you have to set the [aspect ratio](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html) of your plot to 1.

In your link, that is done in this line:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, aspect=1)
```

In your example:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib.patheffects import withStroke

fig = plt.figure()
x = np.arange(1,10,.1)
y3 = np.sin(x)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(1,1)  # 2x2 grid
ax=fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0], aspect=1)
ax.plot(x,y3)
Xc = 6
Yc = 0.5
### This produces an ellipse
circle = Circle((Xc, Yc), 0.25, clip_on=False, zorder=10, linewidth=1,
                edgecolor='black', facecolor=(0, 0, 0, .0125),
                path_effects=[withStroke(linewidth=5, foreground='w')])
ax.add_artist(circle)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That does not work.  Simply replacing `ax=fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])` with `ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, aspect=1)` in the above code does not produce a circle

Comment: It does to me. Edited the answer with your example

Comment: Your full code doesn't work for me on my mac, but it does on my Linux box.  On my Mac (OSX 10.15.7), I'm running python-3.7.3 and matplotlib-3.2.1 (without a backend specified).  On my Linux box (CentOS 8.1) I am running python-3.6.8 and matplotlib-3.0.3 with the backend (`~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`) being TkAgg.  Thoughts?

Comment: No idea, it works for me on both my Mac and Linux machines. It's probably something specific to your Mac environment. you should open a new question to tackle it if you can't find a solution.

Comment: Ok, it actually works on both Mac and Linux.  I recopied and pasted your code into a new file.  I must have been confused about which code I was running.